# Animate.css and Typed.js - Hide typed till animation finishes.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm using Bootstrap, Animate.css and Typed.js to build a webpage. The effect I want is the page to be blank, the `nav` to slide down using animate.css `fadeInDown` when that completes the Typed.js line to start writing and when that completes a chevron (provided by FontAwesome) to animate in using animate.css `bounceInUp`.

I've written the following code but everything just happens at once and the chevron doesn't animate at all.

```
<body>


<!--NAV BAR SECITON-->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid  animated fadeInDown">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="companylogo.png" /></a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li><h3><a href="#">Blog</a></h3></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Main page banner -->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center special">
      <div class="centermaintextline vertical-center">
        <div class="showAndTell">
          <h1>
            <span class="maintextline"></span>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center bottom-box">
        <h1><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Script that should hide the section to be typed.js so the flashing cursor doesn't appear till ready-->
  <!--Also hide the chevron-->
  <script>
    $(document).ready($('.showAndTell').hide());
    $(document).ready($('.fa-chevron-down').hide());
  </script>


  <script src="typed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- thanks http://www.mattboldt.com/ -->


  <script>

    /*This function will execute typed.js and then show the chevron and animate it-*/
    function typingEffect()
    {
      $(".maintextline").typed({
        strings: ["Stuff to be typed"],
        typeSpeed: 100,
        startDelay: 1000,
      });

      $('.fa-chevron-down').show();
      $('.fa-chevron-down').add('animited infinite bounceInUp');


    }

    /*function that should show the block to be typed.js and then execute the function that will typed.js*/
    function showTypingEffect()
    {
      $('.showAndTell').show();
      typingEffect();
    }

    /*call the previous function to get things going after the navbar finishes animating*/
    $(document).ready($('.container-fluid').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', showTypingEffect()));

  </script>

</body>
```

CSS Stuff

```
/*********************************************************
*                                                        *
*           Stuff that affects the first panel           *
*                                                        *
*********************************************************/

/*Makes .jumbotron occupy the full window*/
.jumbotron
{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.jumbotron .container
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right:0px;

}


/*Makes things center vertically in the page, funnily enough*/
.vertical-center
{
  min-height: 85%;  /* Fallback for vh unit */
  min-height: 85vh; /* You might also want to use
                        'height' property instead.

  /* Make it a flex container */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  /* Align the bootstrap's container vertically */
    -webkit-box-align : center;
  -webkit-align-items : center;
       -moz-box-align : center;
       -ms-flex-align : center;
          align-items : center;

  /* In legacy web browsers such as Firefox 9
     we need to specify the width of the flex container */
  width: 100%;

  /* Also 'margin: 0 auto' doesn't have any effect on flex items in such web browsers
     hence the bootstrap's container won't be aligned to the center anymore.

     Therefore, we should use the following declarations to get it centered again */
         -webkit-box-pack : center;
            -moz-box-pack : center;
            -ms-flex-pack : center;
  -webkit-justify-content : center;
          justify-content : center;
}

.vertical-center
{
  min-height: 85%;  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
  min-height: 85vh; /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Remove the default bottom margin of .jumbotron */
.jumbotron .vertical-center
{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/*Everything below here styles the text in the cetner of the page*/
.special
{
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "ocr-a-std", san-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*Make the main keyword underline */
.special a, .special a:hover, .special a:visited
{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color:#fff;

}

.bottom-box
{
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
}

.fa-chevron-down
{

}
/*********************************************************
*                                                        *
*         Stuff that affects the navigation bar          *
*                                                        *
*********************************************************/

.nav
{

}

/*Style the top bar*/
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-top a, .navbar-fixed-top a:hover, .navbar-fixed-top a:visited, .navbar-fixed-top li
{
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  font-family: "futura-pt", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbrand
{
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-fixed-top
{
  position: absolute;
}

.nav h4
{
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}



/*********************************************************
*                                                        *
*         Makes the cursor blink for the typed.js        *
*                                                        *
*********************************************************/

.typed-cursor{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
}
@keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

Comment: fiddle man!! fiddle!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [jQuery ready documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

*The .ready() method is typically used with an anonymous function.*

example :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.showAndTell').hide();
        $('.fa-chevron-down').hide();
        $('.container-fluid').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', showTypingEffect);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: The problem seems to be, looking at the debugger, that all the code is executing at once, it doesn't wait for the animation end firing, or it's detecting that straight away. It hides the elements, the straight away shows them again, and never does animate the chevron.

Comment: I think `.container-fluid` doesn't have CSS animation, so the `animationend` event never triggered. (based on your CSS above)

Comment: That was my first thought but I'm applying it as per the Animate.css GitHub page and I've tested it by adding a `animation-delay: 3s;` to `.container-fluid` which does delay the fadeIn animation by 3 seconds.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/vyawfnmk/. I give `.container-fluid` CSS animation, and it work

Comment: You're right then the container-fluid isn't registering an animation. Question now is why when that method of using it is exactly as the Animate.css says to use it and detect the animations end.

Comment: added `animate.min.css`, and it worked https://jsfiddle.net/vyawfnmk/1/ ... do you forget to include animate.css?

Comment: Now I'm really stumped. Animate.min.css is being called in the header and is there because the animations are working. . There's got to be a difference as I can see the fiddle code is working but other than you call animate as an external resource and I'm calling it as a local resource on the server, I can't see one.

Comment: Fixed it. There was an extra close bracket in the code for detecting the end of the animation. Only realised when I pasted in the jsfiddle version and it worked fine.